# Como detectar que o texto criou novas linhas

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Vamos imaginar eu tenho uma lable e tem um texto com n caracteres.
Sempre que esse texto não cabe ele vai colocando as palavras na linha de baixo.
Como eu detecto que isso aconteceu?

Eu tentei assim

```
    internal int ContarQuebrasLinhas()
    {
        return LBLNomeEvento.Text.Split('\n').Length;
    }
```

Isso funciona quando sou eu que faço essa quebra

```
lable.Text = "aaaaa\naaaaa";
```

Vou mostrar agora a imagem de como apareceria

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como não cabe na mesma linha ele faz quebra de linha

Comment: Mas nesse caso o texto não criou novas linhas... ele apenas está sendo exibido com a quebra por configurações do container... o valor continua inalterado.

Comment: Exatamente. Ele que faz isso automaticamente e eu preciso de saber quando ele faz isso

Comment: Pode sempre tentar dessa forma: `return LBLNomeEvento.Count(r => r == Environment.NewLine);`.

Comment: @JoãoMartins `Enviroment.NewLine` não seria simplesmente `\r\n`?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes, talvez você consiga comparar o atributo Height da label com o ActualHeight... se o segundo for maior, houve quebra de linha e dividindo pelo inicial, talvez você consiga estimar o número de linhas

Comment: Inclua o markup da sua label na pergunta

Comment: @LeandroAngelo sim, é a mesma coisa! É hábito mesmo :)